# Parameter 0 of constructor in type required a bean of type 'org.hibernate.SessionFactory' that could not be found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I had two projects:

1. Project A which is in charge of the view of a website (Spring 3 + JSF + JSP)
2. Project B which is in charge of the logic of that website (Spring 3)

Both of them work just fine in the current version. However, we wanted to migrate project A (developed using JSF and JSP) to Spring Boot.

I started a Spring Starter Project using STS4 and as soon as I try to run the app, this error pops out:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
oct 27, 2021 10:14:12 AM org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter report
GRAVE: 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in {CLASS} required a bean of type 'org.hibernate.SessionFactory' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.hibernate.SessionFactory' in your configuration.
```

The thing is that {CLASS} is in project B, which has its own configuration file that works just fine with the old project A. This is the file that loads that sessionFactory bean in project B:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <bean name="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <bean class="org.foo.bar.PropiedadesEntorno">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <ref bean="entorno" />
                </constructor-arg>
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="configurationClass" value="org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

And the config file of the new project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
        xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd">
    <bean name="entorno" class="java.lang.Integer"> 
        <constructor-arg type="int" value="1" />
    </bean>
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.foo.bar" /> 
    <import resource="classpath*:META-INF/spring/config.xml"/>
</beans>
```

The class that loads that SessionFactory is this one:

```
@Repository
public class ContratoDao extends BaseDao implements IContratoDao {
    
    @Autowired
    public ContratoDao(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        super(sessionFactory);
    }

    ...
}
```

I tried several solutions all around here but i can't get them to work as I can't change project B.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Assuming you are using a recent version of Spring Boot that doesn't support hibernate3 only 5 and up. Next if you are just using Spring Boot and not loading the XML file nothing will happen with that, you will need an `@ImportResource` which points to your XML file to load, if you don't nothing will be loaded (judging from the exception you don't have this, else you would get a `ClassNotFoundException` for the `AnnotationSessionFactoryBean`).

Comment: I just added that annotation to my project and now it shows another error about bean overriding, but I guess that's another problem to face.

Answer (score 0):

You can get Session from EntityManager. Inject EntityManager

```
@Autowired
private EntityManager entityManager;

private Session getSession() {
        return entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
    }
```

and use `getSession()`
in ContratoDao. It may help you to solve this issue.

Comment: The thing is that the class ContratoDAO is one of those that I can't change as it is part of the project that I don't have permissions to update.